# Plugin.MediaManager.Forms: Video will not play from Xamarin.Forms App Data Directory

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm trying to play a video on a Xamarin app using the Plugin.MediaManager.Forms nuget package. The video is stored in the Xamarin App Data Directory so try to play the video by building the path to the folder with the filename.

```
var path = Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, filename);
await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(path);
```

Unfortunately I just get a blank screen when I call `Play(path)`.

I've also tried using FileInfo however I still just get a blank screen.

```
var path = Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, filename);
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(fileInfo);
```

I've tested on both Android, UWP & iOS platforms and see the same result.

Comment: I do not know whether your video files supported by the framework

Comment: This is a standrad MP4 file which play's fine in the native video player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, the Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory path is **/data/user/0/Package name/files/**, I add one .mp4 file in files folder, then the .mp4 video play successfully.

So please confirm that wheather you have mp4 file.

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Button
            x:Name="btnplay"
            Clicked="btnplay_Clicked"
            Text="play video" />
        <video:VideoView HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="200" />
    </StackLayout>

 private async void btnplay_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string filename = "minions.mp4";
        var path = Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, filename);

        await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(path);
    }
```

You can see that there is one minions.mp4 file in files folder, then path is **/data/user/0/demo.demo3/files/minions.mp4**

[image]